# Using string elements in vba formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am stuck to write a formula into cells using vba. I double quoted the strings and tried different combinations, but I still get an `Application-defined or object-defined error.`

The formula I am currently using in VBA:

```
ws_conf.Range("A60").Formula = "=IF(Veraltete_Ratings!A11="""";""""; ""-   "" & Veraltete_Ratings!C11 & "" ("" & Veraltete_Ratings!B11& ""):"" & Veraltete_Ratings!AD11 & "" (vorher "" & VLOOKUP(Veraltete_Ratings!B11;Datenbank!B:BC;54;FALSE) & "")"")"
```

The original formula in Excel:

```
=IF(Veraltete_Ratings!A11="";""; "-   " & Veraltete_Ratings!C11 & " (" & Veraltete_Ratings!B11& "):" & Veraltete_Ratings!AD11& " (vorher " & VLOOKUP(Veraltete_Ratings!B11;Datenbank!B:BC;54;FALSE) &")")
```

Glad for any help.

Comment: For sure, don't use semicolon in vba, just the comma (except your lookup string offcourse)

Answer (score 0):

Refer The below link to know more about **Writing Formulas with VBA Macros in Excel**

https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/writing-formulas-with-macros/

Please refer the below sample, hope which can help u to get an idea for Modifying your code.

**Note:** The below is just sample not for your workbook

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Formula_Property()

      'Formula is a string of text wrapped in quotation marks
      'Starts with an = sign
      Range("B10").Formula = "=SUM(B4:B9)"

    End Sub


    Sub Macro10()
    '
    ' Macro10 Macro
    '

    '
        Range("B14").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[-10]C[-1],Table!R2C10:R370C11,2,FALSE),"""")"
        Range("B15").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=""Total Sales: "" & TEXT(R[-5]C,""$#,###"")"
        Range("B14").Select
    End Sub
```